# Thread safe data structure to check for existence and write if not

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I want to parse a long list of strings with duplicates and save each unique string to an array exactly once. In a multi threaded approach, threads will check a shared data structure for existence and write if it does not exist.

I forget what data structure is appropriate for this.
Anything from Java.util is fine and so are high performance third party libraries.

Comment: Use a ConcurrentHashMap but if your strings are all relatively short (I'd say less than a 100 characters) it's very unlikely that this will give you a noticeable performance improvement - it might even be worse than the single threaded implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection classes in the *java.util* package are not thread-safe in order to provide maximum performance in single-threaded applications. (Vector and Hashtable being exceptions)

There are a few ways to achieve the thread safety you are looking for.

**Sychronized Wrapper**

`Set<String> safeSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());`

This will wrap all the calls to the underlying set in in a synchronized block, locking on the object.  However, That means when a thread is iterating over elements in a collection, all other collection’s methods block, causing other threads having to wait.

**java.util.concurrent Package**

Java 5 introduced concurrent collections that provide much better performance than synchronized wrappers.

There are different flavors: copy-on-write, Compare-And-Swap, and concurrent collections.

The concurrent collections use a special Lock that is more flexible than synchronization.

So for what you are doing, a HashSet is probably a good match, if it was single threaded. In the concurrent package you could use ConcurrentHashMap.

It would look like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

...

 private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
 Map<String, Object> seenStrings = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();



for ( String aString : stringList ) {
    if ( seenStrings.containsKey(aString) ) {
        // Already there
    } else {
        // Not seen yet
        seenStrings.put(aString, PRESENT);
    }
}
```

**Update**
Andy's comment is a good one, I wasn't sure what you wanted to do if you had already seen an item or if you haven't.

You could do this to ensure the check and insert are executed atomically

```
if (seenStrings.put(aString, PRESENT) == null) {
       // Not seen yet
}
```

**Update** In Java 8+, you can create a set backed by the specified map. Effectively a ConcurrentHashSet.

```
Set<String> seenStrings = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
for (String aString : stringList) {
    if (seenStrings.add(aString)) {               
            // Not seen yet
    }
}
```

Comment: "it would look like this" hopefully not. ConcurrentHashSet isn't magical: it can't know that separate calls made to it are supposed to be executed atomically (specifically: using `contains` and `add` like this doesn't work). Instead, use `if (!seenStrings.add(aString))`, and remove the `else`.

Comment: What are you doing with the PRESENT object? If we have to do this extra step just to use a Map, wouldnt a different data structure be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for this purpose. However if you have many writes `CopyOnWrite` approach would be costly.

If you want to remove duplicates consider using `CopyOnWriteArraySet`

Comment: Using a linked list to remove duplicates is literally (and yes I mean literally not virtually) the worst possible implementation.

Comment: Never mentioned removing duplicates.